# How can I use splidejs components in svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, splidejs

I am trying to use a **splidejs** component in my **svelte** application, specifically the [Move Component](https://splidejs.com/components/move/) because I want to use its [move method](https://splidejs.com/components/move/#move), although I would also like to know how to implement any splide component.

I've looked through the documentation and I haven't found an example or description of how to actually implement a splide component, I'm using [Svelte Splide](https://splidejs.com/integration/svelte-splide/) on my app, but I don't think that matters much.

Thank you to anyone who can explain to me how to implement a **splidejs component** in **svelte**.

Comment: Have you tried https://animotion.pages.dev/?

Comment: No I hadn't heard of it but it looks really cool, but I'm having trouble finding how to implement it on my existing project, the docs only go into how to start a new project with it, do you know how I could implement it?